# How to run Say "something" in background in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, audio

I would like to have AppleScript code like this:

```
row 1
say "some long text here"
row 3
```

When it starts to speak text, it same time continues to row 3.

I create my scripts in AppleScript Editor and i don't know enough about process control on OS X to understand backgrounding yet.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
say "some long text here" without waiting until completion
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting Terminal to run the line of AppleScript:

```
set myscript to "say \"some long text here\""
ignoring application responses
  tell application "Terminal"
    do script "osascript -e " & quoted form of myscript
  end tell
end ignoring
```

Comment: Thanks, but my scripts speak tons of times during day, so using this Terminal trick is not elegant enough. Maybe there is some Cocoa/ASOC code i can put to my script?

Comment: @brianBlue Scripting means no code - but you could look at stackoverflow.com once you've gotten enough of a foothold on coding to ask there for help. I've had terminal scripts that run continually and fire every second in some cases when I need to collect data that cannot be done otherwise. Elegant is more about how skilled the artist is as opposed to the tools chosen.